# How to keep special characters intact in IPA with python

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of characters in a word without altering special characters like `ɑ̃`
e.g:

```py
word =  "aplavɑ̃tʁɛ"
list(word)
['a', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'v', 'ɑ', '̃', 't', 'ʁ', 'ɛ']
```

I want to have:
`['a', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'v', 'ɑ̃', 't', 'ʁ', 'ɛ']`

Comment: @RavenCheuk Clearly not yesterday; but see answer now. Rather than leave a comment asking for a notification, click the "Follow" link to be notified when someone answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if a character is a combining character, and if so, keep it together with the preceding character.

```py
import unicodedata


word =  "aplavɑ̃tʁɛ"
characters = []
for char in word:
    if unicodedata.combining(char):
        characters[-1] += char
    else:
        characters.append(char)
print(characters)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'v', 'ɑ̃', 't', 'ʁ', 'ɛ']
```

Unicode facilitates the combination of arbitrary glyphs with joining modifiers (diacritics etc) so that you can build up characters with multiple accents, which is frequently required in IPA and e.g. Vietnamese orthography. (This is sometimes abused in something called "zalgotext".)

Comment: This will throw an ugly traceback if your very first character is a combining one. I don't think that's well-defined in Unicode anyhow.